# User Authentication in a Node.js Google Cloud application

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I need to implement a user authentication system in my Node.js application running in the Google Cloud Platform. GCP provides a few ways to implement authentication, such as using Firebase, as noted here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/authenticating-users

However, i'd prefer to roll my own system. When building Node.js applications in the past, I would often use a MongoDB database to store user information. When the user would login or register, the information would be sent to the proper `/login` or `/register` routes. I would then use `bcrypt` to hash the password, and then save the user document to the database. A JWT would then be generated and sent to the client.

On GCP, it seems the Google Cloud Datastore is the preferred option for NoSQL databases. I would use a `Kind` of `User` and store the user information with hashed passwords. Would this be a good option for storing user information, similar to how i've done it with MongoDB as described above?

Thanks!